# Why does the error keep returning "variable has incomplete type void"?

Tags: c++, void

I'm trying to write a code that will solve Coulomb's Law equation for force between two charged particles (using void) and I keep getting
error: variable has incomplete type 'void'.
The code should measure for r=1 and then loop (adding 3 to r every time) and finishing when r < 60. It will output all of these results.

```
int main() {
float Q_one;
float Q_two;
int rad = 1;
double const k = 8990000000;
cout << "Enter the charge of particle 1." << endl;
cin >> Q_one;
cout << "Enter the charge of particle 2." << endl;
cin >> Q_two;
void force (float Q_one, float Q_two, int rad);
void force = ((k * ((Q_one * .000001) * (Q_two * .000001))) / (rad * rad));
while (rad <= 60) {
    {
        force (Q_one, Q_two, rad);
        cout << "Radius " << (rad) << " ";
        cout << "Force " << (force) << endl;
        rad += 3;
    }
}
```

}

I've tried rearranging this numerous ways and changing how I define 'force' but nothing seems to work. Any ideas as to how I can fix this?

Comment: Hello, I don't get the line `void force (float Q_one, float Q_two, int rad);` it looks like you are trying to declare a function. Is that what you want ? If yes the `void force = ...` don't make sense. (AFAIK `void force = ` will never make sense anyway)

Comment: I'm converting a program to a function. The program worked initially, but now that I'm trying to change it to a function I'm getting this error. I thought to define it as a void I had to write void force(float q_one, float q_two, int rad) but I also have to get it to plug in the numbers and solve for the force for the first output. This might be the wrong spot to do that, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you trying to do.

After fixing some mistake I got this :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    float Q_one;
    float Q_two;
    int rad = 1;
    double const k = 8990000000;
    cout << "Enter the charge of particle 1." << endl;
    cin >> Q_one;
    cout << "Enter the charge of particle 2." << endl;
    cin >> Q_two;
    auto force = [k](float Q_one, float Q_two, int rad) { return (k * Q_one * .000001 * Q_two * .000001) / (rad * rad); };
    while (rad <= 60) 
        {
            auto result = force (Q_one, Q_two, rad);
            cout << "Radius " << (rad) << " ";
            cout << "Force " << (result) << endl;
            rad += 3;
        }
}
```

Demo : [wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/9Ck6oSc42uDAHcfX)

Does it look like what you want ?

Comment: I'm trying to convert it to a function using 'void'. My main issue was trying to get it to define the function as void before putting the actual equation in the loop, but I don't quite understand why it wasn't initially working.

Comment: I'm still a bit of a novice at c++, so I'm sorry if I misunderstand what you're trying to say. I think what you have here is similar to what I initially had before using void, but in this I'm trying to change the code so it uses void in this case. Thanks for the help.

Comment: `void` mean "nothing". So when you write `void force (float Q_one, float Q_two, int rad);` you define a function who return nothing, and take the copy of 3 `float`. The function can ether 1) do nothing. 2) Have some side effect. In your example you don't have side effect, that why I create a lambda who return something

Comment: does it helps ? If not can you try to explain what you mean with "to convert it to a function using 'void'". If it helps please feel free to accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are trying to make a function to calculate force with. You can, for example make it a lambda function:

```
    auto force = [=](float Q_one, float Q_two, int rad)
    {  return ((k * ((Q_one * .000001) * (Q_two * .000001))) / (rad * rad)); };
```

And then you call it in the loop and assign it to let's say `F` like this:

```
    while (rad <= 60) {
            double F = force(Q_one, Q_two, rad);
            cout << "Radius " << (rad) << " ";
            cout << "Force " << (F) << endl;
            rad += 3;
        }
```